# Get a href in input field customizer wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, hyperlink

I'm trying to get a field in the customizer for inserting the link to the LinkedIn profiles of my customer.

Before I made a text field and used the wpautop function. That works very well. Does anybody know a quick way to let the user insert a plain link like example.com what will be displayed like https://example.com? 
With a page _blank please :-)

For my text i used this code:

```
    <?php echo wpautop (get_theme_mod('themename-expression-text') )?>
```

I guess i'll need something like:

```
   <?php echo wpautoahref (get_theme_mod('themename-expression-text'))?>
```

I just can't find it :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it! Definitely to deep into the code today :-)

```
    <a target="_blank" href="<?php echo (get_theme_mod('themename-example-externallink') )?>">Linkedin</a>
```